# I have tried using the 4 axioms to prove that this is not an inner product, but i cant get it

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone guide me on this question please?

State why the following function is not an inner product, for $=(_1,_2)$ and $=(_1,_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $$\left<,\right>=5_1_1−2_2_2$$

Comment: What happens if $u=v=(0,1)$?

Comment: @JVV i have tried many numbers but still i cant prove that it is not inner product, including (0,1), or maybe im making mistakes?

Comment: Well, $\langle (0,1),(0,1)\rangle = -2$. Is this inner product positive definite?

Answer (score 2):

It fails to be positive definite.  Can you find a vector $u$ such that $\langle u,u \rangle \lt 0$?

Comment: sorry sir im not understand that why is it needed to find a vector < 0, if i let u = (0, 1), and <u, u> will get -2

Comment: is it any ⟨u,u⟩ that < 0 is not an inner product?

Comment: That is listed as one of the requirements of an inner product in the Wikipedia article.  Is it not in yours?  We want to say that $\langle u,u\rangle$ is the square of the length of $u$, so it has to be nonnegative.